# Efficient matrix operation in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix, apply, finance

The following code is at the core of my project, unfortunately it is too slow at the moment considering the dimensions of my problem. Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same result?

```
nbassets <- 80
nbrisksource <- 100
nbsimul <- 300000
set.seed(100)
#generate random number for each 100 source of risk in many simulations
random <- matrix(runif(nbsimul*nbrisksource)+0.9,nrow=nbsimul,ncol=nbrisksource)
# random vulnerability to each source of risk for each of 120 assets
EL_decomp <- matrix(runif(nbassets*nbrisksource),nrow=nbassets,ncol=nbrisksource)
#initiate matrix to store asset returns
asset_ret <- matrix(NA, nrow=nbsimul,ncol=nbassets)


ptm <- proc.time()
#loop through each asset
 for (i in 1:nbassets){
  #determine if the asset has been impacted by any source of risk, if yes return is -1, otherwise 0
  asset_ret[,i] <- apply(matrix(EL_decomp[i,], nrow=nbsimul,ncol=nbrisksource,byrow=TRUE) < random,1,all)-1
}
print(proc.time() - ptm)

ptm <- proc.time()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have it 18 times faster, basically skipping all the matrix writing and taking advantage of R's recycling:

```
n_80     <- 80
n_100    <- 100
n_300000 <- 300000
set.seed(100)
mat_300000_100 <- matrix(runif(n_300000*n_100), nrow=n_300000, ncol=n_100)
mat_80_100     <- matrix(runif(n_80    *n_100), nrow=n_80,     ncol=n_100)
mat_300000_80  <- matrix(NA, nrow=n_300000, ncol=n_80)
```

First, remove the matrix because `>` recycles vectors. Have to transpose because `>` applies vector by column and not by row. And, if you can, use optimized functions such as `colSums` instead of `apply`. Here, `apply(v,2,'all')` can be replaced by `colSums(v)==length_v`.

```
ptm <- proc.time()
for (i in 1:n_80) mat_300000_80[,i] <- colSums(mat_80_100[i,] < t(mat_300000_100))==n_100-1
print(proc.time() - ptm) # 17s
```

Eventually, do `transpose()` only once outside of the loop. (Or even never since your values are completely random in your example...)

```
ptm <- proc.time()
mat_100_300000 <- t(mat_300000_100)
for (i in 1:n_80) mat_300000_80[,i] <- colSums(mat_80_100[i,] < mat_100_300000)==n_100-1
print(proc.time() - ptm) # 8s
```

Comment: you're right! but even with the assignment, `apply` makes a gain of less than 0.5 s

Comment: Thanks. Granted your code is much faster, but it doesn't do the same operation. Namely, in my code the all() function is applied on a row by row basis, therefore while you apply it to the entire matrix. The results are not identical. Granted my example was poorly chosen, and I have edited it such that it is now clear that the two operations lead to different answers.

Comment: Just to be clear: `apply(matrix(EL_decomp[i,],nrow=nbsimul,ncol=nbrisksource,byrow=TRUE)` returns an array of booleans while `all(mat_80_100[i,] < mat_100_300000)` returns only one boolean

Comment: @TheTime, you almost, almost had it, there is what I take to be a type in your elegant one line (replace nbassets by nbrisksource) like so: `apply(EL_decomp, 1, function(x) (colSums(x < t(random)) == nbrisksource) - 1L)`. If you don't mind posting this as an answer, I would then accept it. Otherwise I'll post it myself. Thanks again.

Comment: @SimonWuya, you're right, I didn't see the subtlety. It's corrected, and still fast.

Answer (score 2):

Things can be vastly improved. The following is a comparison of old and new code:

```
nbassets     <- 80
nbrisksource    <- 100
nbsimul <- 300000
set.seed(100)
random <- matrix(runif(nbsimul*nbrisksource)+0.9, nrow=nbsimul,ncol=nbrisksource)

EL_decomp     <- matrix(runif(nbassets    *nbrisksource), nrow=nbassets,     ncol=nbrisksource)
asset_ret1  <- matrix(NA, nrow=nbsimul, ncol=nbassets)
asset_ret2  <- matrix(NA, nrow=nbsimul, ncol=nbassets)

ptm <- proc.time()
for (i in 1:nbassets){
  #determine if the asset has been impacted by any source of risk, if yes return is -1, otherwise 0
  asset_ret1[,i] <- apply(matrix(EL_decomp[i,],nrow=nbsimul,ncol=nbrisksource,byrow=TRUE) < random,1,all)-1
}
print(head(asset_ret1))
print(proc.time() - ptm) #182s on my old mac

#improved version
ptm <- proc.time()
randomt <- t(random)
asset_ret2 <- apply(EL_decomp, 1, function(x) (colSums(x < randomt) == nbrisksource))- 1L
print(head(asset_ret2))
print(proc.time() - ptm) #14s
print(identical(asset_ret1,asset_ret2))
```

Comment: Just a note: In case of `NA`s,  there might be a mismatch between `apply(x, 1, all)` and `colSums(x) == n`; you might need to count the non-NA values in each column first than assume it's "n".